# Finding ideals of $F_2[C_2]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

I'm trying to find the ideals of $F_2[C_2]$

I believe the elements are $(0,1,x) $

So far I have the ideal {0} I can't seem to spot any others, have I made a mistake or missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming you are representing the elements of $C_2$ with $\{1,x\}$.)

$C_2$ is a basis for the space, so there are at least $2^2$ elements. You forgot $x+1$, which squares to zero. So $(x+1)$ is another (and the only other) ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I was missing something. It makes sense now.

Comment: @ForTheGlory No problem!